# node app not displaying through apache2 reverse proxy

Tags: meteor, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, reverse-proxy

I'm just getting started with meteor and I've deployed the sample todos app to my server which runs apache2 webserver.

The meteor app runs fine through domain.com:3000 but when I use the URL domain.com/todos the page is blank BUT viewing the page source shows there is code there.

So I expect I've screwed up the reverse proxy, but cannot figure it out. Please can you help me?

My domain.conf file in apache2/sites-available looks like this:

```
    <VirtualHost mydomain.com:80>
    ServerAdmin mark@mydomain.com
    ServerName monkl
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.dom

    <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /todos>
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000
   </Location>
```

My server is Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) and I'm using an apache2 webserver, meteor 1.3

Many thanks, Mark

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the Apache logs: /var/log/apache2? Error and access. Sometimes when I've run into problems here it's also been related to user permissions. Make sure the Apache user has read access to the files.

Comment: No, nothing obvious Bryan :-(

Comment: I had a look at the console in Chrome and noticed an error on the "blank" page domain.com/todos:

Exception in onResRdy: TypeError: Cannot read property 'htmlRes' of undefined